# JQTouch animation flicker

Tags: jqtouch

I have been working a JQTouch app. The functionalitly is correct however my animations on some menu items flicker, especially when you click a back link. The strange thing is it is only on certain menu items.

All pages are loaded in the same way via AJAX.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

site can be viewed at:

http://www.alliancerail.co.uk/ip/iphone.html

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Runs fairly smoothly for me, without any flickering that I can see (though I know what you're talking about). What version of jQT are you using? Also... identifying the specific menu items that flicker would help others try to troubleshoot.

Comment: Apolgies, I had left the incorrect file uploaded. The flicker should be back now. The only pages that run smoothly are the contact and news pages all of the others flicker especially on returning to the main menu (i.e. clicking a back button). One thing I should mention is that I am dynamically loading specific content items in to the main html page from other html pages.

Comment: What version of jQTouch are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra closing `</div>` that appears after "about" and right before "gnwr." Not sure if this will end up fixing your flicker problem...

Comment: Thanks. have taken the </div> out, still have the flicker when navigating back to main menu.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading content dynamically. Sometimes the jqt animates to the new page before that page has content. Try including more content in index.html such as the about or contact pages. You can also write your own ajax routines that get fired from onClick events bound to the anchor tag on your home page.

The goog group is a great resource -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jqtouch

Comment: I could understand your point when navigating to another page but I dont think this explains the animation flicker when navigating back to the main menu. I do think the issue is to do witht he dynamic content though. I have changed the code slightly so that before it navigates back to the home page the page is emptied of content, the animation runs smooth in this instance allbeit the content is removed and it animates from a blank page.